# fopen in php 7 with change different operating system

Tags: php, fopen

i create simple code  that check if file exists and create one if return false
in windows every thing is good and code work but when i upload the code to linux
server not work because every file created twice
in this order.

```
      if (file_exists(self::COOKIES_FOLDER.DS.$email . ".txt") === false) {
                 $fh = fopen(self::COOKIES_FOLDER.DS.$email . ".txt", 'w');  
                 fclose($fh);
            }
```

[image]

Comment: seems there are spaces in the email. trim it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `$email` contains some spaces in the end. it always good to `trim` emails and usernames.

```
$file = self::COOKIES_FOLDER . DS . trim($email) . ".txt";

if (file_exists($file) === false) {
     $fh = fopen($file, 'w');
     fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: thank you Works Fine now but strange thing In windows works fine

Comment: Same code we just trim it so should work on all machines. Happy coding mate.